# UIPageControl not appearing when Vertical is selected

Tags: ios7, uipageviewcontroller, appdelegate, uipagecontrol

I can get the `UIPageControl` to work when the `PageViewController` Navigation style is set to `Horizontal`, however when I choose `Vertical` the `UIPageControl` does not appear horizontal or vertical.

I am setting the appearance of my UIPageControl in the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return YES;
}
```

Is there a way to make it appear in a vertical position? The code above works when the `Horizontal` option is selected for navigation but not when the `Vertical` is selected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is to use `UIPageViewController` with **vertical** orientation and also display the `UIPageControl` vertically. I tried to do that, but it seems that the `UIPageControl` related to the `UIPageViewController` is not accessible directly.

However, I found a very satisfactory workaround to your problem. Use `UIScrollView` with **pagingEnabled** and manage the `UIPageControl` in the scrollView's delegate methods. To display the `UIPageControl` vertically, you can use

```
pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
```

I made a sample application demonstrating this workaround. [Here](https://github.com/aksh1t/iOS-POC-Projects/tree/master/PageControlExample) is the download link. Consider accepting the question if it helped you solve the problem, thanks.